# XamlParseException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shell, xaml

I'm trying my application, but an error comes up saying 'XamlParseException was unhandled". This is what is showing in the error window:

Cannot create instance of 'Shell' defined in assembly 'myProgram, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'myProgram;component/Shell.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

Here's my line 1 in Shell.xaml:

"Window x:Class="myProgram.Shell"

Comment: When looking at the window with the error message, is there more information under the header "InnerException"? Sometimes that will give you more detail on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Shell.xaml. Looks like some XAML is breaking there. Check below things:
1) All bindings are ok.
2) Styles used are ok and present in style
3) any converter used are ok.